# How to hide jQuery datatables

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-data

How do I to hide jQuery datatables, when I want to toggle the datatable's visibility? The problem is if I write hide statement it only hides the rows, not the headers and footer. How can I hide datatable fully?

For hiding, I used the below code:

```
 var oTable = $('#example').dataTable(); // 'example is the table id'
 oTable.hide();
```

Comment: @Rob : Yes it also gives same result

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#example').parents('div.dataTables_wrapper').first().hide();
```

Answer (score 16):

i think the best way is to include the table inside a div and hide the div

```
 <div id='divTable'>
     <table>
     </table>
 </div>

 $('#divTable').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

For me (and I know this is a wierd need) I needed to hide the main table but keep the results (i.e. X results of X filtered).

`$('div.dataTables_wrapper thead,div.dataTables_wrapper tbody').hide();`

The above fixed it for me. If you have a footer you would need to add `,div.dataTables_wrapper tfoot` as well.